# $ \forall n \in N: \forall m \in N: n<m \Rightarrow \exists r \in N: n+r=m$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Use the principle of mathematical induction to show that$ \forall n \in N: \forall m \in N: n<m \Rightarrow \exists r \in N: n+r=m$.

My attempt:

Let $ B=\lbrace n \in N \mid \forall m \in N: n<m \Rightarrow \exists r \in N: n+r=m \rbrace $.

We will prove that B is inductive the set.

a) $ 1 \in B$ since if $n=1, 1<m$ and this implies that $m\neq 1$ and since $ m \in N $, there exists $r \in N$ such that $1+r =m$.

b) Now we will prove that for all $n \in R, n \in B \Rightarrow  n+1 \in B$.
That is, we will prove that

$ \forall m \in N: n+1<m \Rightarrow \exists r \in N: (n+1)+r=m$. Here I got stuck.

Comment: You have to remove the $∀n$ quantifier from the definition of set $B$,

Comment: In order to prove that $1 \in B$, you have to show that: for every $m$, if $1 < m$ then $m=1+r$ for some $r$. Saying that "it is obvious" is not exactly what we expect...

Comment: Do you have a definition of $<$? Otherwise, what are the axioms for $<$? The "usual" one is $n < m \leftrightarrow \exists k (k \ne 0 \land m=n+k)$.

Comment: I can use theorems about natural numbers, for example the following: "Every natural number other than 1 can be written as the sum of 1 plus some other natural number."

Comment: Ok that's enough; it amounts to: $\forall m (m \ne 1 \to \exists k (m=k+1))$

Comment: Base case: $n=1$. If $1 < m$ then $m \ne 1$; thus $m=k+1$ and we have found the needed $r$.

Comment: These are two other results that I have tried to use: "$ \forall m \in N: m \geqslant 2 \Rightarrow \exists r \in N: 1+r = m $." and "$ \forall m \in N: m \geqslant 2 \Rightarrow m-1 \in N $."

Comment: Maybe also: "if $n+1 < m+1$, then $n < m$?